# Angular - Animate on page load

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I am trying to create an animation in which the top div slides out revealing the contents of the page underneath. Following is my animations

```
animations: [
   trigger("myAnimationTrigger", [
      transition('void => *', [
       style({ transform: 'translateY(0%)'}),
       animate('1500ms',style({transform: 'translateY(100%)', display:'none', opacity: 0}))
     ]),
   ])
]
```

Currently the animation takes place but the red div comes back. I thought using displaying none would make it disappear at the end of animation. Secondly if I wanted the animation to reveal the page by rolling the div up what would be the transformation for that?

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vha4wa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do as in the angular docs in [Defining animations and attaching them to the HTML template](https://angular.io/guide/animations#defining-animations-and-attaching-them-to-the-html-template) and set different states on the animation (shown and hidden in this case) and the transition from shown to hidden:

```
animations: [
  trigger("myAnimationTrigger", [
    state('shown', style({
      transform: 'translateY(0%)'})
    ), state('hidden', style({
      transform: 'translateY(100%)', display:'none', opacity: 0})
    ), transition('shown => hidden', [
      animate('0.5s')
    ]),
  ])
]
```

Then, set a variable in your component to save the current state:

```
state = 'shown';
```

And change this variable of state after the component is loaded in AfterViewInit:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  setTimeout( () => {
    this.state = 'hidden';
  }, 200);
}
```

This variable is used in the template triggering the animation:

```
[@myAnimationTrigger]="state"
```

And you can see the final result on [this stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ax8fvt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

The animation will be done only the first time when ngAfterViewInit() is executed and state property changes from 'shown' to 'hidden'.